# Why are some websites seemingly immune to self-signed certificate MitM attacks?

Tags: public-key, tls, certificates, man-in-the-middle

I recently did an experiment using MitM to gain account information (username and password) while accessing websites. I used two PCs in the scenario; one as the target, running Internet Explorer, and one as the attacker, running ettercap. One attempt (pretending to be steamcommunity.com) yielded information; the target accepted the attacker's fake CA self-signed certificate presented via the MitM attack. The other attempt (pretending to be facebook.com) didn't even allow me to add an exception for the self-signed certificate on the target machine. So the question is, why did one website allow me to add an exception while the other one didn't?

Comment: I added an answer for this question but it really belongs on the [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i'll ask there too. i need answers as many as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is [HTTP Strict Transport Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security)
.

> When a web application issues HSTS Policy to user agents, conformant
>   user agents behave as follows:
>
> 1. Automatically turn any insecure links referencing the web application into secure links. (For instance,
>      http://example.com/some/page/ will be modified to
>      https://example.com/some/page/ before accessing the server.)
> 2. **If the security of the connection cannot be ensured (e.g. the server's TLS certificate is not trusted), show an error message and do
>      not allow the user to access the web application.**

(emphasis mine)

On websites that have it configured, many browsers will not let you add an exception for untrusted certificates.